# Erro ao tentar dar um update dentro de um foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho esse foreach

```
private void UpdateAzureDiscountGroupReseller(IQueryable<Reseller> model)
        {
            Reseller resellerObj = new Reseller();

            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                resellerObj.AzureDiscountGroupId = null;
                resellerObj.AcceptContractCustomer = item.AcceptContractCustomer;
                resellerObj.Id = item.Id;
                resellerObj.Name = item.Name;
                resellerObj.Alias = item.Alias;
                resellerObj.Enabled = item.Enabled;
                resellerObj.ResellerMpnId = item.ResellerMpnId;
                resellerObj.ServiceApiUser = item.ServiceApiUser;
                resellerObj.ServiceApiPassword = item.ServiceApiPassword;
                resellerObj.HomeTemplateId = item.HomeTemplateId;
                resellerObj.CategoriesIds = item.CategoriesIds;
                resellerObj.AcceptContractCustomerId = item.AcceptContractCustomerId;
                resellerObj.AcceptContractDate = item.AcceptContractDate;
                resellerObj.PathServiceContractAzure = item.PathServiceContractAzure;
                resellerObj.PathPartnershipContractAzure = item.PathPartnershipContractAzure;

                _resellerService.Update(resellerObj);
            }
```

Se eu colocar a chamada ao **Update** fora do foreach, funciona. Porém, eu posso ter mais de um reseller com a mesma FK e o que eu quero é deletar o Grupo. Não posso dar um **cascadedelete** na tabela. Então a solução, para evitar violação de integridade, foi, antes do **Delete** no grupo, eu dou um update na FK no **Reseller**, passo pra null e então deleto. Ok, para um único registro que tem a FK funciona bem, porém para dois ou mais Reseller's com a mesma FK, preciso de um foreach e nesse caso dá esse erro:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running
>   in the session.

No método Update está assim:

```
public void Update(Reseller reseller)
        {
            var existingResellerWithSameAlias = GetByAlias(reseller.Alias);
            if (existingResellerWithSameAlias != null && existingResellerWithSameAlias.Id != reseller.Id)
                throw new KeyDuplicatedException("There is a reseller with the same ID or Alias on Database");

            _resellerRepository.Update(reseller);

            cache.Update(reseller.Alias, reseller);

            _logTracker.Register(LogTrackType.Update, reseller);
        }
```

E quando chega aqui é que o erro explode:

```
_logTracker.Register(LogTrackType.Update, reseller);
```

Como faço para atualizar vários registros ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Eu tenho dúvida de usar o using com o contexto. Como eu utilizo o using e o contexto e dando um dispose para matar qualquer transação aberta e ir para uma nova?

Comment: Tentando isso, mas está dando esse erro: ***'IDBContext': type used in a using statement must be a implicity convertible to 'System.IDisposible'***. Eu fiz isso: ` using (IDbContext contexto = _context)....`

Comment: Mudei para DBContext ao invés de IDBContext, mas ele não aceita o new DBContext() no using e nem injetando no Construtor

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente existem dois problemas:

O primeiro é que como você recebe um `IQueryable`, você talvez esteja com uma representação da sua coleção de itens ao invés da coleção em si. Isso acontece por que o IQueryable é chamado apenas no momento em que é utilizado, por exemplo:

```cs
var resultado = query.Where(x => x.Id < 10); // Aqui a consulta SQL é definida mas ainda não é executada

foreach (var item in resultado) // Aqui a consulta é efetivamente executada e os resultados retornados
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Para que isso não aconteça, é necessário usar o método `.ToList()`, que converte em uma lista comum, desvinculada dos registros do banco de dados.

O outro problema é que você está criando o objeto fora do foreach e quando você atribui os valores a ele e salva, ele é repopulado com as referências (como objetos relacionados, por exemplo) e essas referências podem não ser atualizadas na próxima iteração do foreach, causando perda de consistência de dados. Para resolver isso, basta criar o objeto dentro do laço.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```cs
private void UpdateAzureDiscountGroupReseller(IQueryable<Reseller> model)
{
    foreach (var item in model.ToList())
    {
        Reseller resellerObj = new Reseller();
        resellerObj.AzureDiscountGroupId = null;
        resellerObj.AcceptContractCustomer = item.AcceptContractCustomer;
        resellerObj.Id = item.Id;
        resellerObj.Name = item.Name;
        resellerObj.Alias = item.Alias;
        resellerObj.Enabled = item.Enabled;
        resellerObj.ResellerMpnId = item.ResellerMpnId;
        resellerObj.ServiceApiUser = item.ServiceApiUser;
        resellerObj.ServiceApiPassword = item.ServiceApiPassword;
        resellerObj.HomeTemplateId = item.HomeTemplateId;
        resellerObj.CategoriesIds = item.CategoriesIds;
        resellerObj.AcceptContractCustomerId = item.AcceptContractCustomerId;
        resellerObj.AcceptContractDate = item.AcceptContractDate;
        resellerObj.PathServiceContractAzure = item.PathServiceContractAzure;
        resellerObj.PathPartnershipContractAzure = item.PathPartnershipContractAzure;

        _resellerService.Update(resellerObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keven, mesmo assim não funcionou, exceto que eu ainda não passei para um `ToList()`, como comentou, porém se comento essa linha, `_logTracker.Register(LogTrackType.Update, reseller);` aí funciona. Fiz um método de update só pra esse método sem a linha acima e agora está ok, mas vou dar uma olhada na sua sugestão com `ToList()`.

Comment: Coloca a mensagem e o StackTrace da exceção

Comment: Já está no post original: `New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.`

Comment: Coloca o stacktrace, por favor.

Comment: Resolvi removedo essa linha: `_logTracker.Register(LogTrackType.Update, reseller);`. Então, como não poderia remover essa linha no método original e esses updates são para uma situação específica, criei outro método de update, sem a referida linha.